# HTML and other formatting

Tags: python, html

is there a way (using python and lxml) to get an output of HTML code like this:

```
<table class=main>
<tr class=row>
</tr>
</table>
```

instead of one like this one:

```
<table class=main><tr class=row></tr>
</table>
```

Only tags named "span" in div-tags can be appended. So things like:

```
<div class=paragraph><span class=font48>hello</span></div>
```

are allowed.
Thanks a lot for any help.

Comment: `lxml` doesn't strike me as the right tool for generating HTML. Have you considered a template-driven HTML generator instead?

Comment: Your HTML is invalid in the second example, class names should be quoted: `<div class="paragraph"><span class="font48">hello</span></div>`

Comment: actually, looking again, it's all wrong... fortunately BeautifulSoup will fix that for you.. check the two examples below, and you'll see that they have the class names quoted in both!

Comment: Hm..is someone accessible via email? I just saw that I have a specific problem...

Comment: Specific problems are what SO was made for, create a new question!

Answer (score 2):

you could insert a line break before every "<" with a regex

Answer (score 2):

Another option would be using BeautifulSoup:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup    
html = "<table class=main><tr class=row></tr></table>"    
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)    
print soup.prettify()
```

Output:

```
<table class="main">
 <tr class="row">
 </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: ha!  beat me to it by 30secs :)

Comment: @MarkF6, it's better for the SO community if all information regarding problems is accessible to everyone. Conversations over email prevent this.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered the [`prettify()`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#pretty-printing) method from the module [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) ?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup as bs

html = '<table class=main><tr class=row></tr>\
</table>'

print bs(html).prettify()
```

outputs:

```
<table class="main">
 <tr class="row">
 </tr>
</table>
```

**Note** - it will add some indentation to the output, as you can see.